Store and use the results of a page-sliced measure value across multiple pages
grateful for any guidance on the multi-use of single tables and measures in PowerbI - I've spent weeks trying to figure this out.
I have a **page **with 4 slicers. Each slicer is based on a different small table (yes/no, 1-10, etc)
I then have some measures - "vol", "start date", "End date".
These measures are calculated on the fly by Power BI depending on what is selected in the slicers (plus some static data). So far so good.
My static data covers 12 countries.
I need a page for each country.
I then need a summary tab at the end which totals the vol from each of the pages and displays the start/end date for each country.
Essentially I need to 'capture' the 'page-specific' values of the measures and store them somewhere and do the same for pages 2,3,4 etc to then pull them into summary.
is this possible?
Any guidance VERY gratefully received.
When I try to do this I get error value - I assume because the same measure has different values across the pages so the summary page cannot reconcile which is needed...

You can select slicers on the page, press Ctrl-C, then switch to each other page and press Ctrl-V to insert copies of these slicers. When you insert it you'll see the following confirmation:

Choose "Sync".
Now slicers on page and other pages are synced - when you choose something on page the same is choosen on other pages.
You can control slicer synchronization by mean of Sync Slicer pannel (menu View|Sync Slicers):

Using this pannel you can also hide slicers on other pages (see red arrow) if you wish.
Having this slicers synced up makes the measure to be calculated the same way on each page.

Thanks - this works fine per page - but I also need a SUMMARY page at the end which totals the measures from each page.

You can try to create additional measures, calculated with cleared filter on country. Something like this:
Summary Measure = CALCULATE([Measure], ALL(Countries))
